# npm Bootstrap not working on new react project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I've just created a new project with react cli and installed npm bootstrap.

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

I have then tried bootstrap in App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <h1>It Works!</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

but it's not working.

This is my package.json:

```
    {
      "name": "myapp",
      "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there anything else that I need to do in order to make it work?

Comment: I do not see that you have added scripts or bootstrap css inside the index html. You tried that?

Comment: Sorry, package.json updated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You installed the `bootstrap` npm module, but that only downloads the files to your `node_modules/` directory. You haven't yet actually required bootstrap within your project itself.

Try doing this above `import './App.css'`

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

You could also try linking to the `bootstrap.min.css`file in your `public/index.html`, if the import does not work.

Comment: helped! Can you add how to get bootstrap js files to be working and document where it is elaborated well?